# Adobe SDK Parsing Text

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, text-extraction, acrobat-sdk

I was looking in to Adobe acrobat and one of the features I noticed was that when you hit control + F there is a popup to find and replace text. Once you hit the replace button on the popup, all the text inside the entire PDF Document becomes split into small sections surrounded by a box. Even after I close out of the find and replace pop up, the sections remain. Is there anyway to parse text like this with adobe acrobat SDK?

Comment: these boxes are the unique text objects, some pdf files may contain even single letter per object (though visually they form a word).

Comment: With the Adobe Acrobat SDK, you can use the same search feature that is built into [Acrobat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FOverview_Searching%2FSearch_plug-in.htm) (their documentation doesn't say anything about whether the UI is the same though).

Are you looking to recreate the UI or leverage what exists in Acrobat already?